# Contingency table using survey package in r

Tags: r, survey

I am trying to construct a multilayer contingency table in percentage using `svytable` command in `survey` package. While computing, the sum of row percentages are presented as 50 and respective percentages in every cell of the contingency table are share of this 50 percent. I want to convert this into 100. Is there any way to do this contingency table where I can show the share of each cell in table out of 100 percent and also the sum total in every row? I don't want to change 100 into 200 in code `a <-prop.table(a, 1)*100`

```
df <- data.frame(sex = c('F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'M', 'F', 'F'),
                 married = c('1','2','1','1','2','1','2','1'),
                 area = c('1', '2', '2', '1', '2', '1', '2', '2'),
                 weight = c(1.12, 0.55, 1.1, 0.6, 0.23, 0.23, 0.66, 0.67))
d.s <- svydesign(ids=~1, data=df, weights=~weight)
a <-ftable(addmargins(svytable(~sex+married+area, d.s)))
a <-prop.table(a, 1)*100
a
```

Along with this, is there any way to transfer output in R to excel easily. Thank you.

Comment: you can use `write.csv("path/to/file", a)`

Comment: Yes. But writing separate CSV files for every table is quite hectic. I am looking for any procedure where I can write the table output in exactly the same format in a single excel file in easy way (not with so many lines of code).